# Alarms in API higher than 19

Tags: android, android-alarms

I'm trying to set an Alarm. When I debug my program on emulator with API 14, everything is ok: I have log even if screen is off or if I manually close the app from recent. But when I debug it on real device with API > 19, I can't see log in these cases: screen is off or I close the app from recent. How to deal with it?

Main code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
} else {
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

AlarmReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("try");
    }
}
```

I also tried to change targetSDKversion in graddle to 18, but it didn't help..

Comment: pl go through the docs from this link http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html . This link contains the sample http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/Scheduler.zip

Comment: @Shaan_B your link contains method `set` which doesn't work in API > 19